# Using (x)malloc with preallocated pool

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, heap-memory, allocator

Is it possible to use one of the major allocators with an existing block of memory (pool)? Say I have a block of allocated memory and I want to use jemalloc or tcmalloc to manage that block as a custom heap. Is this possible or do I have to write an allocator from scratch that employs one of these major allocator's strategies?

Comment: If you want to use `jemalloc` etc then you don't need to preallocate memory yourself. I'm trying to think of a use-case here.

Comment: FWIW, below is a link to an online C++ book describing overloading operator new and delete, and also placement new. Also, if I recall correctly, Stroustrup has good discussions of custom allocators in his books, e.g. "The C++ Programming Language", 4th ed.  http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Frames.html